# How to minimize the delays in collecting all promises in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, promise, angularjs-service, angular-promise

Please see my code below. In 'for' loop, in each iteration I am making an Ajax call and pushing promises into array and resolving all these promises with $q.all. But it is causing delays as I need to wait till all promises collected in the 'for' loop and then after all promises are available then I need to resolve them one by one in $q.all.

```
var promises = [];

for (var i = 0; i < dashboardslayoutArray.length; i++) {
    dashboardData.dashletteBeansList = [];
    dashboardData.dashletteBeansList[0] = dashboardslayoutArray[i];

    var dashlettePromise = DashboardsDataService.getTabDetails(dashboardData);
    promises.push(dashlettePromise);
}

$q.all(promises)
    .then(function(data) {
        // all promises were resolved here
    });
```

Instead what I would like to do is, resolve the promise the soon it is available in the 'for' loop itself without pushing it into 'promises' to use in $q.all. Some thing like,

```
for (var i = 0; i < dashboardslayoutArray.length; i++) {
    dashboardData.dashletteBeansList = [];
    dashboardData.dashletteBeansList[0] = dashboardslayoutArray[i];

    var dashlettePromise = DashboardsDataService.getTabDetails(dashboardData);

    dashlettePromise.then(function(data) {
        ...
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error);
    });
}
```

But this is not working as expected. Here second promise result effecting first promise result, etc. Is there any fix for this?

As per  @Benjamin Gruenbaum suggestion I have changed it to

```
angular.forEach(dashboardslayoutArray, function(dashboardslayout) {
    dashboardData.dashletteBeansList = [];
    dashboardData.dashletteBeansList[0] = dashboardslayout;

    var promise = DashboardsDataService.getTabDetails(dashboardData);

    promises.push(promise);

});
```

But how can I reduce the delay even here?

@Benjamin Gruenbaum, I am summarizing my question below:

```
var promises = [];
angular.forEach(dashboardslayoutArray, function(dashboardslayout) {
    dashboardData.dashletteBeansList = [];
    dashboardData.dashletteBeansList[0] = dashboardslayout;

    var promise = DashboardsDataService.getTabDetails(dashboardData);

    promises.push(promise);

});

$q.all(promises)
    .then(function(allData) {

        allData.forEach(function(data) {

            for (var dashVar = 0; dashVar < data.tabDetails.length; dashVar++) {
                var dashletteId = data.tabDetails[dashVar].dashletteId;
                var axisType = data.tabDetails[dashVar].axisType;
                // ...   draw c3 chart ...
            }
        });
    });
```

I need to make multiple Ajax calls, so I have used the above approach which is working just fine. Here all my Ajax call results are independent, none of these depend on others. Using the data returned from each Ajax call, I draw a chart using Angularjs C3 directives.

But the problem I am facing is delay. To draw four C3 charts I need to make four ajax calls, using $q.all,  I can start drawing C3 charts only after all four Ajax calls finishes (resolved or rejected). Instead what I would like to do is, the soon any one Ajax call finishes (resolved or rejected), I would like to start drawing the C3 chart based on the result of that particular Ajax call. So I have used the following approach to avoid delays in queuing all the promises.

```
angular.forEach(dashboardslayoutArray, function(dashboardslayout) {
    dashboardData.dashletteBeansList = [];
    dashboardData.dashletteBeansList[0] = dashboardslayout;

    var promise = DashboardsDataService.getTabDetails(dashboardData);

    promise.then(function(data) {

        for (var dashVar = 0; dashVar < data.tabDetails.length; dashVar++) {
            var dashletteId = data.tabDetails[dashVar].dashletteId;
            var axisType = data.tabDetails[dashVar].axisType;
            // ...   draw c3 chart ...
        }
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error);
    });

});
```

My final question is, is it right approach the way I have used `promise.then(function (data)` inside  `angular.forEach(dashboardslayoutArray , function(dashboardslayout)` to avoid the delays? are there any potential problems in this approach? I hope, I have expressed my question clearly, if not please let me know, I will try to make the plunkr.

Comment: Make sure you're __not__ referencing `i` in your `then` handler - otherwise you end up with the infamous closure-loop problem and will have to switch to `dashboardlayoutArray.forEach` (or angular.forEach) instead of a for loop.

Comment: I have changed it  to   angular.forEach(dashboardslayoutArray , function(dashboardslayout) {
           dashboardData.dashletteBeansList = [];
        dashboardData.dashletteBeansList[0] = dashboardslayout;       
        
              var promise = DashboardsDataService.getTabDetails(dashboardData);

              promises.push(promise);

          });

Comment: I don't really understand - consider making an isolated plunkr.

Comment: "I am ... resolving all these promises with $q.all". No you are not! Why? Because `$q.all()` does not *cause* promises to be resolved - rather, it *responds* to promises being resolved (or rejected). Get you mind round that, and ask yourself if the question is valid. I believe it is not.

Comment: Got the point @Roamer, thanks. Benjamin, to make a plunker in specific to  my problem requires lot of coding to be provided and also I feel it may unnecessary waste your time to go through all that code related to charting directives, etc. So I am editing my question with a summary at the end. Please let me know, if helps you to understand my requirements clearly.  Thanks.

Comment: Please learn to [format your code properly](http://jspretty.com). What you posted is complete chaos, and impossible to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My final question is, is it right approach the way I have used promise.then(function (data) inside angular.forEach(dashboardslayoutArray , function(dashboardslayout) to avoid the delays?

Yes, this exactly what you should have been doing. `$q.all()` allows you to do something after an entire set of promises has been resolved. Since that's the opposite of what you wanted to do, `$q.all()` was not the right tool for the job here.

You never showed us what you had inside the `then()` in your second code example, but given that you said *"second promise result effecting first promise result, etc"*, it's very likely that Benjamin Gruenbaum's suspicions were correct and that it was the `i` loop variable that was causing problems. Switching to `.forEach()` would have fixed that.

Comment: Thanks JLRshine,  I am accepting the answer. You are right after changing it to .foreach the expressed problem was fixed.